# Display result of simple computation like usable in tikz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz picture where I use some self defined numbers in order to simpler change them.  In the arguemt to `\draw` simple computations are performed.  But now I want to typeset the result of the same computation.

So I want to have some macros where I can set numbers that I can use in tikz coordinate computations and also typeset the computed value.

Here is an example that does not yet work because it should print `(1.5,0)` instead of `(0.5+1,1-1)`.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\x{0.5}
\def\y{1}
\def\delta{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (\x,\y) -- (\y+\delta,\y-\delta);
\end{tikzpicture}
Wrong: The line goes from $(\x,\y)$ to $(\x+\delta,\y-\delta)$\\
Desired: The line goes from $(\x,\y)$ to $(1.5,0)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear moderators and power-users of tex.se, I know that this question is not so much about tikz but I did not find a better tag and the site required me to usa at least one tag.

Comment: check out `\pgfmathsetmacro`. There are other ways to extract coordinate of existing points. But in `pt` not `cm`. So it's up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pgfmath` outside a `tikzpicture`, since `\x`, `\y` and `\delta` are all defined globally.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\compute}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}

\def\x{0.5}
\def\y{1}
\def\delta{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (\x,\y) -- (\y+\delta,\y-\delta);
\end{tikzpicture}
Wrong: The line goes from $(\x,\y)$ to $(\compute{\x+\delta},\compute{\y-\delta)})$\\
Desired: The line goes from $(\x,\y)$ to $(1.5,0)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\xdef`.

solution from https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/4293/reutilisation-de-coordonnees-tikz-dans-le-corps-du-texte

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\def\x{0.5}
\def\y{1}
\def\delta{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (\x,\y) -- (\x+\delta,\y-\delta);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\x+\delta}
\xdef\coordx{\xx}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\y-\delta}
\xdef\coordy{\yy}
\end{tikzpicture}

Wrong: The line goes from $(\x,\y)$ to $(\coordx,\coordy)$\\
Desired: The line goes from $(\x,\y)$ to $(1.5,0)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I take it I have to define an extra `\coord...` for every computation I want to do and I have to do it all inside the tikz picture. I would prefer a macro that I can just use at the place where I want to typeset the result because I have quite some computations.

Comment: There is also `\global\let\xx=\xx`.  Alternatively, you can print the results in a node.